# Adding SSL to TcpListen server?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I have made a simple server using TcpListener and it works great but now I would like the connection to be secure.

The clients that connect would be web servers so does it matter if the certificate is trusted or is that just for web browsers?

I have found muddled answers that are not straight forward!

**UPDATED**

When I share this application would the user have to make a certificate as well or could all users use the same one? Would using the same one not cause security issues or can you bind the certificate to the application so it cannot be seen?

In other words whats the best practise?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) class:

> Typically, the
>   SslStream  class is used with the
>   TcpClient  and TcpListener  classes.
>   The GetStream  method provides a
>   NetworkStream  suitable for use with
>   the SslStream  class.

There is a full example on the link.